# Compare and insert a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a `sql` query which compares current month and previous month values. 
Below is my query

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate VARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @Year VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Month VARCHAR(100)

SET @CurrentDate = (SELECT  MAX(Date_Key) AS CurrentMonth FROM LoanFact)

SET @Year = (SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@CurrentDate,5,2) = 1 THEN (SUBSTRING(@CurrentDate,1,4) - 1) ELSE SUBSTRING(@CurrentDate,1,4) END )
SET @Month = (SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@CurrentDate,5,2) = 1 THEN '12' ELSE (SUBSTRING(@CurrentDate,5,2) - 1) END )


;WITH cte AS (

SELECT DISTINCT  
CurrentMonth.ID, 
CurrentMonth.Date_Key, 
--CurrentMonth.Status AS CurrentMonth_Status, 
--previousMonth.Status AS PreviousMonth_Status,
--CurrentMonth.System_Key AS CurrentMonth_System_Key,
--previousMonth.System_Key AS previousMonth_System_Key,
CASE WHEN CurrentMonth.Status = PreviousMonth.Status THEN 0
WHEN CurrentMonth.Status <> PreviousMonth.Status AND CurrentMonth.Status = 'A' AND PreviousMonth.Status = 'N' then 115
WHEN CurrentMonth.Status <> PreviousMonth.Status AND CurrentMonth.Status = 'N' AND PreviousMonth.Status = 'A' then 150
WHEN CurrentMonth.System_Key = previousMonth.System_Key THEN 0
WHEN CurrentMonth.System_Key <> previousMonth.System_Key AND CurrentMonth.System_Key <=10 AND previousMonth.System_Key >=10 THEN 304
WHEN CurrentMonth.System_Key <> previousMonth.System_Key AND CurrentMonth.System_Key >=10 AND previousMonth.System_Key <=10 THEN 303
WHEN ((ISNULL(SeedAndChemYesNo, 'No') = 'Yes')) THEN '559'
END [Service_Action_type]


FROM 

(
SELECT  
ld.ID,
ld.Status ,
SUBSTRING(lf.System_Key, 3, 2) AS System_Key,
lf.Date_Key
FROM    
Fact lf
INNER JOIN Dimension ld ON lf.LKey = ld.LKey
LEFT JOIN CustomerFact ltcf ON lf.LKey = ltcf.LKey AND lf.Date_Key = ltcf.Date_Key
LEFT JOIN OrganizationDimension od ON od.Organization_Key = ltcf.Organization_Key

WHERE   
SUBSTRING(CAST(lf.Date_Key AS VARCHAR(100)),1,6) = SUBSTRING(@CurrentDate,1,6)
) CurrentMonth


INNER JOIN 

(

SELECT  
ld.ID,
ld.Status ,
SUBSTRING(lf.System_Key, 3, 2) AS System_Key,
lf.Date_Key
FROM    
Fact lf
INNER JOIN Dimension ld ON lf.L_Key = ld.L_Key
LEFT JOIN CustomerFact ltcf ON lf.L_Key = ltcf.L_Key AND lf.Date_Key = ltcf.Date_Key
LEFT JOIN OrganizationDimension od ON od.Organization_Key = ltcf.Organization_Key

WHERE   
SUBSTRING(CAST(lf.Date_Key AS VARCHAR(100)),1,4) = @Year
AND CASE WHEN  SUBSTRING(CAST(lf.Date_Key AS VARCHAR(100)),5,1) = 0 
        THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CAST(lf.Date_Key AS VARCHAR(100)),5,2), '0','')
         ELSE SUBSTRING(CAST(lf.Date_Key AS VARCHAR(100)),5,2) END = @Month) PreviousMonth

ON CurrentMonth.LoanNumber = PreviousMonth.LoanNumber
LEFT JOIN [SeedAndChem] Issac ON PreviousMonth.ID = Issac.ID
```

Right now because of the `case statement` the `service action type` is updated if one condition is satisfied and is checking for other conditions.

I want to able to update the `service action type` based on all conditions that is, if more than one condition is satisfied I want the code column to update to those values by creating duplicate ids if necessary.

Below is the sample data I am getting right now.

Sample Data:

```
ID          Service_Action_type
2653467     150
2523379     150
```

But I want the data to be like below if more than one conditions satisfy.

```
ID          Service_Action_type
2653467     150
2653467     303
2653467     559
2523379     150
2523379     304
2523379     559
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Can't picture what you want... can you add sample data, current results, and desired results?

Comment: I added the sample data. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I just have to break the `case statement` into three different `case statements` and then `UNPIVOT` those three columns from the three different `case statements`.

Thanks everyone for your time and help.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Changes needed :

## 1 Previous month Table Left join Current month

## 2 In the select statement you have to retrieve previousmonth.id, previousmonth.date_key

```
    select 
    PreviousMonth.ID, 
    PreviousMonth.DateKey,
    Current_month.ID, 
    Current_month.DateKey
    , 
    CASE WHEN Current_month.Status = PreviousMonth.Status THEN 0 
    WHEN Current_month.Status <> PreviousMonth.Status AND Current_month.Status = 'A' AND PreviousMonth.Status = 'N' then 115
    WHEN Current_month.Status <> PreviousMonth.Status AND Current_month.Status = 'N' AND PreviousMonth.Status = 'A' then 150
    END [Service_Action_type]

     from
    (
    select '2653467' ID, 'jan' Datekey ,''Service_Action_type,'A'Status 
    union 
    select '2523379' ID,'Feb' Datekey ,''Service_Action_type,'B'
    union 
    select '2523379' ID,'march' Datekey ,''Service_Action_type,'N'
    ) PreviousMonth 
    Left Join
    (
    select '2523379' ID,'Apr' Datekey ,''Service_Action_type,'N' Status
    union
    select '2653467' ID,'Apr' Datekey ,''Service_Action_type,'N' Status
    ) Current_month 

    on Current_month.ID = PreviousMonth.ID
```

Hope this works !